# Is there a way for me to pass parameters from one function to another in an if statement?

Tags: python, function, if-statement, parameters

I am currently producing a menu-driven program. Here is a code snippet:

```
    def main():
    intro()
    loop = True
    while loop:
        print("\n<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< ||| >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>")
        print("\nChoose your option below:")
        print("1 - Patient Registration")
        print("2 - Total Patients")
        print("3 - Total Sales")
        print("Q/q - Quit")
        choice = str(input("Your choice?"))
        print("\n<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< ||| >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>")
        menu(choice)
        
def intro():
    print("Welcome to CTI System.")
    print("This system is used to track and manage Covid-19 testing")
   
def menu(choice):
    if choice == '1':
        patientRegistration()   
    elif choice == '2':
        testType(pcr,antigen)
    elif choice == '3':
        totalSales()
    elif choice == 'Q' or choice == 'q':
        print("\nThank you for using this program.\n")
        exit()
    else:
        print("\nInvalid choice! Please select from the list of choices.\n")
        loop = False
```

When choosing the first choice, it will prompt the user to gather information. Afterwards, once the user is done with the first choice, the user will be prompted to continue, if 'N' then it will go back to the main menu.

This is where where problem starts. I want to choose the 2nd choice in the menu which is the total number of patients. How can I pass the parameters from the first condition to the second?

Your help is greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: after you chose an option you want to choose again?

Comment: you could use a list and store all the choices so far.

Comment: yes. The 1st choice is where the body count will come from. When the user deems the count is enough, they can discontinue entering the details and be moved back to the main menu. They can then choose to display the count when the choose the 2nd option.